# How to generate bubble chart (Chart.js) using data from database FILTERED by user in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, chart.js

I'm new to Django and stuck in one place that didn't seem to be such a problem. I'm trying to do dynamic bubble chart using Python, Django, MySQL and Chart.js. I have organizations stored in my database. They have some attributes like name, income, amount of recipients, etc.I'm showing it to user and he can filter it (for ex he can display organizations that only have more recipients than specified by user). Then I want to create a bubble chart that shows these organizations. I managed to do that, but using all database records (static solution, without user interaction). So, on my bubble chart now I can see everything and I would like to make it dynamic - dependant of user input (showing only organizations that are filtered). Filtered data are in filter.qs in myuserlist1.html file.
Now I use the code below in my views.py to have all records from database in JSON format under defined URL:

```
class ChartData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        organizations = Opp.objects.all().values()
        data = list(organizations)  
        return Response(data)

    def search(request):
        user_list = User.objects.all()
        user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
        return render(request, 'user_list1.html', {'filter': user_filter})'''
```

Url that I use for store results:

```
url(r'^api/chart/data/$', ChartData.as_view()),
```

This is part of my chart.html file:

```
<script>
    {% block jquery %}
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
    var endpoint= form.attr('action')

    var dynamicColors = function() {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data){
            //...... some logic there
        }
    })

</script>
```

I don't know how to approach it. I thought to make JSON from filtered data an locate it under URL instead of all data from database but I don't know how to do it. I don't know how to access filtered queryset from View. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make HTTP POST request instead of GET to pass JSON data to a backend. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    data: {
        "organisation": "organisation_name"
    },
    success: function(data){
        //...... some logic there
    }
})
```

This would pass `data` as JSON serialized object to Django view.

And then on the Django view you can deserialize the organisation and filter the model:

```
import json

def get(self, request, format=None):
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    organisation_name = json_data.get("organisation")
    organizations = Opp.objects.filter(name=organisation_name).values()
    data = list(organizations)  
    return Response(data)
```